# X axis custom intervals when posixct data type using axis.Date()

Tags: r, visualization

I have a data set where the X axis variable is  Date / Time data. I find the following syntax works when the X axis variable is a Date but when it is a date-time it does not seem to work.

What I wanted was the X axis here to have (say) weekly labels.

Any ideas how to make this work in plot(). Don't want to switch to ggplot etc.

[image]
This does not work:

```
plot(x = data$Time,y=data$foobar,
     xlab = "Date / Time",
     ylab = "y-foo-bar",main = "foo",xaxt="n")
    axis.Date(1,data$Time,
              at=seq(as.POSIXct("2020-04-01 16:36:00 IST"),
                     as.POSIXct("2020-05-01 16:36:00 IST"),by="weeks"))
```

Nor this:

```
axis.Date(1,data$Time,at=seq(as.Date("2020/04/01"), 
                                                 as.Date("2020/05/01"),by="weeks"))
```

For more context:

```
class(data$Time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

data$Time[500]
[1] "2020-03-24 08:18:00 IST"
```

Comment: It's not `axis.Date` you should be using, it's `axis.POSIXct`. Let the S3 method dispatch call the right method, and do just `axis(etc)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Many thanks!  Let me try that.

Comment: @RuiBarradas If I change to just axis() even  the places where axis.Date() was working does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `axis.POSIXct`?

Answer (score 0):

I would define ticks mark positions and labels beforehand. Use `axis` without labels then `mtext`, since with its `las=` argument you're able to rotate the labels.

Using `strftime` you may extract weeks (or else, just lookup `?strftime`) and subset the time points.

```
weeks <- strftime(dat$time, "%W")
ats <- dat$time[!duplicated(weeks)]
labs <- strftime(ats, "%m-%d")

with(dat, plot(x=time, y=x, type="l", main="foo", xaxt="n"))
axis(1, at=ats, labels=FALSE)
mtext(labs, side=1, line=.75, at=ats, las=2)
```

[image]

I omitted the year, since it might be redundant information. You could also omit the month by using two `mtext`s in different lines and also omit the duplicates.

---

*Data*

```
set.seed(33720)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(time=seq(1585034280, (1585034280 + n*24*60*60), length.out=n),
                  x=cumsum(rexp(n)))
dat$time <- as.POSIXct(dat$time, origin="1970-01-01")
```